# IntelliJ IDEA + JBR11 uninstalled but still appears in Spotlight Search

Tags: spotlight, macos

I have uninstalled the JBR11 version of IntelliJ and installed the standard version, but both versions appear in Spotlight Search. How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you uninstall/install it?

Comment: @Thorbjørn With JetBrains Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a corrupted spotlight index.

See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Comment: Hmm... any idea how to figure out what folder needs to be re-indexed? "Applications" has the JetBrains Toolbox but not any of the actual IDEs, it seems.